Unable to get SSO token from CloudAdapter in Teams Bot in Outlook App
I have a Teams BOT App where I get the SSO token using CloudAdapter, and have added the below code to get user token from CloudAdapter:
     const userTokenClient = context.turnState.get(context?.adapter?.UserTokenClientKey);
     const tokenResponse = await userTokenClient.getUserToken(
            context.activity.from.id,
            BOT OAuth Connection Name,
            context.activity.channelId,
            magicCodeString
);

There is link unfurling logic where we show a initial card with refresh action when the link unfurls, which then refreshes to show a user specific card on refresh with more details.
To do so, on card refresh when the handler onAdaptiveCardInvoke() is called I get the SSO token from Cloud Adapter and do the further authentication checks.
While I am able to get the SSO token in Microsoft Teams when I paste a valid unfurlable link and also view the user specific details in Teams.
When I paste the same link in a new email in Outlook, I get a basic card but on refresh, when handler onAdaptiveCardInvoke() is called, tokenResponse in the above code is undefined.
As there is no SSO token in case of Outlook, user specific views for Outlook cannot be shown to the user.
Earlier I was using BotFramework Adapter to achieve this.
And with that, SSO token would come in both Teams and Outlook.
As Bot Framework Adapter is deprecated, I have recently updated to CloudAdapter, post which this issue is seen.
Also, on debugging further I can see that the difference in case of Teams and Outlook is that in Teams value of context.activity.channelId is "msTeams " but in case of Outlook its "m365extensions".
And for the same user, the value for context.activity.from.id is coming differenly in Teams and Outlook
Anyone facing this issue or able to get SSO token in Outlook App?

Could you please share the error logs from your browser if you try it in browser version of Outlook, if any?

@ChetanSharma-msft
I tried in Outlook browser, but there are no specific error logs for this failure.
Just that value of  context.activity.from.id is different in case of Outlook and Teams and hence when we pass this value to getUserToken(), in case of outlook the response is undefined

@ChetanSharma-msft
Are there any code samples for getting SSO token using Cloud Adapter that are applicable for Teams as well as Outlook

@Naina you can use the below sample which uses sso token with CloudAdapter and applicable for Teams as well as Outlook.
Regarding more about your issue, there are few more users who are facing issue related to token with cloudAdapter and we are checking this from our end also.
Meanwhile you can refer this sample-
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-sso/csharp
